# Вывести комментарии при загрузке страницы в WordPress

Tags: javascript, php

Есть такой кусок кода в файле single.php в wordpress:

```html
<div id="show-comments" class="show-comments textcenter">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-text="<?php esc_html_e('Show Comments', 'veen'); ?>" >Click me!</a>
</div>
```

При клике на текст "Click me!" отображаются комментарии.
Нужно чтобы этот код выполнялся и комментарии отображались автоматически при загрузке страницы т.е без клика на "Click me!". Как это сделать?

Comment: Что то не понятно чего вы хотите. В чём проблема? Создайте блок комментариев и добавьте туда их

Comment: Вы нашли тот кусок кода, который отвечает у вас за вывод комментариев? Вот его вставьте в нужную секцию для отображения

Comment: Так я не могу понять что именно то вставить? Если я вставляю просто <?php esc_html_e('Show Comments', 'veen'); ?> оно не пашет.